# SSH tput warning/notice (error?)

Tags: linux, ssh

I recently started receiving the following error when running commands directly through the `ssh` command:

> tput: No value for $TERM and no -T
>   specified

The command I'm running from one linux box (we'll refer to as **alpha**) to box **beta** to produce the error is:

```
[dtbarne@alpha ~]$ ssh beta ls
```

Everything seems to work fine, I just get 33 lines of the aforementioned error. If I try running the same command to another server, like `[dtbarne@alpha ~]$ ssh charlie ls`, I do not see the error, so it seems to be isolated to **beta**.

However, if I jump into a session with just `[dtbarne@alpha ~]$ ssh beta` and then run ls, I never see the errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most probably there's a `tput` command in the user's `.bashrc` on `beta`, and it doesn't bother to check whether the shell is interactive.  This will not only break `ssh` but also various programs that invoke the shell for filename expansion (file names with wildcards in `vi`/`nvi`/`vim`, Perl's `<*>` glob operator, etc.).

With Bourne/POSIX-compatible shells you're supposed to either test for the `i` flag in `$-` or test for `$PS1` being nonempty (the former being the official way); with `csh`/`tcsh` you test `$?prompt`.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I suspect this line in my `.bashrc` to be the culprit: `export PS1='\[$LightGreen\][\t] [\u@\H \W]\$ \[$NC\]'`. Added this recently, but now it seems when I comment the line out, I gett the same error lines, but they now display after the command output rather than before.

Comment: My suspicion, from seeing that, is that it's the lines where you set `$LightGreen` and possibly `$NC` that actually produce the error. Also, don't set `$PS1` if it isn't interactive.

Comment: You suspect correctly. I'm `D'oh`ing about now. That is indeed the problem. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Got it working properly with: http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/bashref/IsthisShellInteractive.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
ssh -t host ls
```

or

```
env TERM=xterm ssh host ls
```

Try to redirect the error stream with your shell, if you still see the error messages this means it comes from the remote server. If not, it comes from your client.
Termcaps errors occurs mostly when the environment variable "TERM" is not properly set.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. The first solution sort of works. No errors, but the output is formatted different and it appends a closed connection message. The second solution unfortunately doesn't work at all. Regardless, I'm looking to fix the source of the problem rather than work around it.